# Can someone tell why my linked list isn't displaying correctly? (C programming)

Tags: c

Can someone tell me why my code is only printing the last value in the linked list, not really good at coding so help would be useful!!

**this is the code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
  int data;  //element
  struct node * next;  //address of next node
} node_t;

node_t * create(int n );
void display(node_t *head);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int n=0;
  node_t * HEAD=NULL;
  printf("Enter number of nodes: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  HEAD=create(n);
  display(HEAD);
    return 0; 
} 

node_t * create(int n) {
  node_t * head=NULL;
  node_t * temp=NULL; 
  node_t * p=NULL;
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {   // this is just reading the nodes
    temp=(node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    printf("\n Enter the data for node num %d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
    temp->next=NULL;
  } 
  if (head==NULL) {   //if list is item
    head = temp;
  } else {    // this is linking the items.
    p =head;
    while (p->next !=NULL) {
      p=p->next;
      p->next=temp;
    }
  }
  return head;
}

void display(node_t *head) {
  node_t *p = head;
  while (p !=NULL) {
    printf("\n%d->",p->data);
    p=p->next;

  }
}
```

**this is the output:**

> > Enter number of nodes:  3
> >
> > Enter the data for node num 1:  2
> >
> > Enter the data for node num 2:  4
> >
> > Enter the data for node num 3:  1
> >
> > 1->

Comment: memory leak....you wrote this code  on your own?

Comment: Kind of, following a youtube tutorial lol.. Oh gosh im not good with malloc and stuff. How do i fix this?

Comment: How many times do you set `p->next=temp;`? What happens to each `p->next` when you do?

Comment: i actually didnt realise it was being replaced, oops im so bad at this! Thanks though

Comment: No your not, your just paying the price to learn -- we all start out making the same mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wanted to do is something but what you did is something else.

You are allocating, then losing the reference to it. And reallocating. The `head` of the linked list is still empty. You pass it and you wait for something to show up. Nothing happens.

```
node_t * ttemp;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {   // this is just reading the nodes
    temp=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if( temp == NULL){
       fprintf(stderr,"error in malloc");
       exit(1);
    }
    printf("\n Enter the data for node num %d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
    temp->next=NULL;
    if( i == 0) head = temp,ttemp=temp;
    else{
        ttemp->next = temp;
        ttemp=ttemp->next;       
    }  
  } 

  return head;
```

Here the memory is allocated and reference is stored. Head is changed to and points to the beginning.

Don't forget the free the memory you allocated. When freeing memory of linked list, `free` each of the node's memory not just of the `head`.

Also don't cast the result of `malloc`.

```
node_t * create(int n) {
  node_t * head, *temp, *ttemp, *p;
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {   // this is just reading the nodes
    temp=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if( temp == NULL){
       fprintf(stderr,"error in malloc");
       exit(1);
    }
    printf("\n Enter the data for node num %d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
    temp->next=NULL;
    if( i == 0) head = temp,ttemp=temp;
    else{
        ttemp->next = temp;
        ttemp=ttemp->next;       
    }  
  } 
  return head;
  }
```

Also you must have this also..call it when you are done working with the list.

```
void freemem(node_t* head){
    node_t *temp;
    while(head){
        tenp=head;
        head=head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Full code would be like this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
  int data;  //element
  struct node * next;  //address of next node
} node_t;

node_t * create(int n );
void display(node_t *head);
void freemem(node_t* head){
    node_t *temp;
    while(head){
        temp=head;
        head=head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int n=0;
  node_t * HEAD=NULL;
  printf("Enter number of nodes: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  HEAD=create(n);
  display(HEAD);
  freemem(HEAD);
  HEAD=NULL;
    return 0; 
} 

node_t * create(int n) {
  node_t * head, *temp, *ttemp, *p;
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {   // this is just reading the nodes
    temp=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if( temp == NULL){
       fprintf(stderr,"error in malloc");
       exit(1);
    }
    printf("\n Enter the data for node num %d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
    temp->next=NULL;
    if( i == 0) head = temp,ttemp=temp;
    else{
        ttemp->next = temp;
        ttemp=ttemp->next;       
    }  
  } 

  return head;
}

void display(node_t *head) {
  node_t *p = head;
  while (p !=NULL) {
    printf("\n%d->",p->data);
    p=p->next;

  }
}
```

Comment: why do we have to exit if temp is NULL? Also, do i just do free(head) or like how do i free the little nodes?

Comment: @Rita.: Because then you are sure that memory is not allocated. So you would terminate the program.

Comment: @Rita.: Also try to implement whatever I said...use `freemem` and  learn to use a debugger

Answer (score 2):

For the code below:

```
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {   // this is just reading the nodes
    temp=(node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    printf("\n Enter the data for node num %d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
    temp->next=NULL;
  }
```

You are allocating `temp` over and over again and only using the last one.

My I suggest:

```
  node_t* head = NULL;
  node_t* tail = NULL;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {   // this is just reading the nodes
      temp=(node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
      printf("\n Enter the data for node num %d: ",i+1);
      scanf("%d",&(temp->data));

      if (head == NULL) {
           head = temp;   // first one
      }
      else {
          tail->next = temp;
      }
      tail = temp;
   }
   return head;
```

Comment: So you added a tail, and so does tail represent the last element in the list? im still a little confused that tail is pointing to temp but then it becomes temp?

Comment: Every iteration of the loop, your newly allocated node, `temp`, gets appended to the end of the list. Hence, the existing end of list pointer, `tail`, needs to point to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just a question of misplaces closing braces `'}'` in `create`

```
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {   // this is just reading the nodes
    temp=(node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    printf("\n Enter the data for node num %d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
    temp->next=NULL;
  // } this needs to go to end of loop 
  if (head==NULL) {   //if list is item
    head = temp;
  } else {    // this is linking the items.
    p = head;
    while (p->next !=NULL) {
      p=p->next;
    } // one step up is here
      p->next=temp;
    //} This needs to go one step up
  }
 } // <-- end of loop is here
```

and here is same logic of yours

node_t * create(int n) {

```
    node_t * head=NULL;
    node_t * temp=NULL;
    node_t * p=NULL;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {   // this is just reading the nodes
            temp = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
            if( temp ) {
                    printf("\n Enter the data for node num %d: ",i+1);
                    scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
                    temp->next = NULL;
                    if (head == NULL) {   //if list is item
                            head = temp;
                    } else {    // this is linking the items.
                            p = head;
                            while (p->next)
                                    p=p->next;
                            p->next=temp;
                    }
            } else {
                    printf("\n oops malloc !! ");
            }
    }
    return head;
```

}